I want to find a movie about a rich man who faked bankruptcy in order to find who is really loyal to him?
I want to find a movie I watched 15-20 years ago.
The plot is about a rich man who faked his bankruptcy in order to find out whether there are people who really love him and are really loyal to him. His intention was to do this for a couple of days and to go back to the original state of being the rightful owner of everything. To do this the rich guy transferred (in some legally acceptable way) all of his possessions (companies and real estate) to his best friend who was also some kind of vice president of his companies.
But what happened after couple of days passed was that the friend didn't want to turn back the possessions back.
In some way the movie is similar to The Game with Michael Douglas but with little different main story.
I don't remember who played the main character in the movie. I thought of Michael Douglas or Anthony Hopkins but couldn't find a similar movie with either of them.

Maybe "Greedy" from 1994, with Kirk Douglas in leading role?!

Has some elements of "Greedy" as IvanaMNE suggests, but in that movie there was no theft, just the fake bankruptcy.  Might be closer to "Life Stinks" with Mel Brooks, but that was all about a bet, not about someone's loyalty (but everyone he made the bet with was crooked, so it could fit anyway).

This sounds a lot like Road to Ruin from 1991, starring Peter Weller. As I recall, he wants to see if a woman he meets is only after his money, so he enlists the help of his business partner to transfer his wealth. Hilarity then ensues. Here's a synopsis from Rotten Tomatoes:

A rich American playboy falls for a woman in Paris but before tying the knot, he decides to test her true motives by arranging a scheme whereby he temporarily writes off his millions to a business partner. When the gal proves her love is for real, the playboy finds that the partner is out to swindle him out of the bucks, so the two lovers must outsmart him to regain the dough.





This is the movie.
(I put this commentary here because I am not sure that it is obvious that I marked this answer as the right answer)
